# Google Sheets automatically changing date format while setting data in sheet using Google APIs

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a project where I need to collect data from an API, store them in a matrix and set that data in a Google Sheet using the **Google-Sheets-APIv4** with **Node.js**. Two key in that API are object.**start_date** and object.**end_date** which return date strings in the format for e.g **"2021-09-22"** ie. yyyy-mm-dd. I want to convert that date to **dd/mm/yyyy** format. The function I have implemented for the same is:

```
function changeDateFormat(dateString){
  let a=dateString.split('-');
  let t=a[0];
  a[0]=a[2];
  a[2]=t;
  //console.log(a.join('/'));
  return `${a.join('/')}`;
}
```

The code works fine and I have used it in the manner shown below:

```
 let checkin=`${changeDateFormat(`${tenancy.start_date}`)}`;
 console.log(checkin);
 let checkout=`${changeDateFormat(`${tenancy.end_date}`)}`;
 console.log(checkout);
```

**tenancy** in the code above is an object. The output that I get in the console is
[image: which is the desired output] which is the desired format, which shows that algorithm for changing date is working fine too.

Also, my code for adding the data in the sheet is

```
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    range:"MySheet!A2:AC",
    valueInputOption:"USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {values : newData} 
/*newData is a 2-D array where each row has several data fields in the form newData[i]=[propertyName,id,......,check-in,checkout,.......]*/
  });
```

However, when I add the data in the sheet, the date fields are entirely jumbled up where some have the desired **dd/mm/yyyy** format while others have the same **yyyy-mm-dd format** as shown in the image [image]

I am not being able to solve the problem as I cannot find any error in the code either but the output is completely jumbled as it's working in some cells but not working in other cells. What might be a possible workaround for this problem? I will gladly provide any other information or data regarding the problem or my code if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal and your situation as follows.

- You want to set the number format of the cells to `dd/mm/yyyy`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- For example, when the values of `[["2021-01-02", "02/01/2021"]]` are put to the Spreadsheet using the method of "spreadsheets.values.append" in Sheets API with `valueInputOption` of `USER_ENTERED`, each value is put as the date object. But it seems that the number format is different.
- In order to use the same number format, in this answer, I would like to set the number format of `dd/mm/yyyy` to the cells using the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate".

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set the value of `sheetId`.

```
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
  auth,
  spreadsheetId,
  range: "MySheet!A2:AC",
  valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
  resource: { values: newData },
});

const sheetId = "###";  // <--- Please set the sheet ID of "MySheet".
const resource = {
  auth,
  spreadsheetId,
  resource: {
    requests: [
      {
        repeatCell: {
          range: {
            sheetId: sheetId,
            startRowIndex: 1,
            startColumnIndex: 12,
            endColumnIndex: 15,
          },
          cell: {
            userEnteredFormat: {
              numberFormat: {
                pattern: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                type: "DATE",
              },
              horizontalAlignment: "RIGHT", // <--- Added
            },
          },
          fields: "userEnteredFormat",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource);
```

- When above modified script is run, the number format of the columns "M" to "O" is changed to `dd/mm/yyyy`. This is from your sample image.
- If you want to modify the format and range, please modify above script.
- And, at above script, the batchUpdate method reflects all rows of the columns "M" to "O". So I think that in this case, this batchUpdate method might be able to achieve your goal by only one time running.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Tanaike. The solution worked perfectly. Just one more doubt. After the batch update, the horizontal alignment of the date cells become unorganized. While some cells have data at their right while other cells have data at their left. How can I make the horizontal alignment uniform?

Comment: @the_namikaze Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Now, I added the request for setting the horizontal alignment of the cells in my sample script. Could you please confirm it? For example, if you want to set the alignment to the left, please modify `RIGHT` of `horizontalAlignment: "RIGHT"` to `LEFT`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#HorizontalAlign)

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly fine!. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes did it. Thanks again for being so helpful!

Comment: @the_namikaze Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.