# Google Sheets python api - how to write values to sheet while preserving sheet formatting?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

When I write data to sheet using spreadsheets.values.update, the existing sheet formatting in the overwritten cells is wiped out.

```
request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_ID, range="Sheet1!A2", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": retrievedData}).execute()
```

Is there a way to preserve the sheet's formatting, and essentially write the values as values only?

Obviously I could write the values to some other worksheet and then reference those values in my desired worksheet, but if I can accomplish the objective directly, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I saw your question, I thought that your situation might be related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67124572) (But, this thread is for Node.js.). If my understanding is correct, in the case of your question, I would like to propose the following modification.

In this modification, at first, the cell format of all cells in the sheet is retrieved. After the value of `retrievedData` was put, the retrieved cell format is reflected to the sheet. By this, the cell format before the value is put is kept. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_ID, range="Sheet1!A2", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": retrievedData}).execute()
```

##### To:

```
spreadsheet_ID = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = 'Sheet1' # Please set the sheet name. In your script, it's "Sheet1".
retrievedData = [[,,,]] # Please set your value.

obj = sheet.get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_ID, ranges=sheetName, fields='sheets(data(rowData(values(userEnteredFormat))),properties(sheetId))').execute()

request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_ID, range=sheetName + "!A2", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": retrievedData}).execute()

body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "rows": obj['sheets'][0]['data'][0]['rowData'],
                "range": {"sheetId": obj['sheets'][0]['properties']['sheetId']},
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
            }
        }
    ]
}
resp = sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_ID, body=body).execute()
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- Related thread.

  - [Google Sheets automatically changing date format while setting data in sheet using Google APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67124572)

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing `valueInputOption` from `"USER_ENTERED"` to `"RAW"`

```
request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_ID, range="Sheet1!A2", valueInputOption="RAW", body={"values": retrievedData}).execute()
```